# Difference in modules when running rspec from "rspec spec" and rspec "spec/services/my/module"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

My test:

```
RSpec.describe Populators::Fipe::Brand, type: :service do
  before(:all) do
    ::Populators::Fipe::Brand.new.perform
  end

  it "update records and do not create new ones" do
    expect{
      ::Populators::Fipe::Brand.new.perform
    }.to_not change{
      ::Brand.maximum(:id)
    }
  end
end
```

When I run:

**rspec spec**

Result:

Failure/Error: ::Populators::Fipe::Brand.new.perform
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `perform' for #<Brand:0x007fdcb6fb2788>
     # ./spec/services/populators/fipe/brand_spec.rb:5:in`block (2 levels) in '

When I run:

**rspec spec/services/populators/fipe/brand_spec.rb**

Result:

Populators::Fipe::Brand
  update records and do not create new ones
  creates table
  fills name
  fills combo_code

Finished in 1.04 seconds (files took 6.33 seconds to load)
4 examples, 0 failures

**EDITED:**

**I have the two classes:**

models/brand.rb

services/populators/fipe/brand.rb

**What the code is trying to do:**

When Populators::Fipe::Brand (service) performs its operation,
it populates the Brand (model) with data from a webservice.
But if the Brand (model) already exists, it only updates.

**What rspec is doing:**

But it seems that rspec is trying to call the method "perform" in the "models/brand.rb"
instead of the correct "services/populators/fipe/brand.rb".
Don't know why..

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can replace `::Populators::Fipe::Brand` with `described_class`, secondly the `::` means forcing upmost context possible. Your error simply says the `Brand` class doesn't have some method, I think what you meant to write here is `::Populators::Fipe::Brand` instead of `::Brand`. Try changing your code to

```
RSpec.describe Populators::Fipe::Brand, type: :service do
  before(:all) do
    described_class.new.perform
  end

  it "update records and do not create new ones" do
    expect{
      described_class.new.perform
    }.to_not change{
      described_class.maximum(:id)
    }
  end
end
```

Comment: Piotr, thanks for the "described_class", I will use in future specs, but the error is still happening.. I edited the explanation of the problem, maybe you have some other insight.. Thanks again